# Broken socket & unable to log into MySQL with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, laravel

I have tried all the other solutions out there for fixing how Laravel connects to MySQL, to the point where I have broken my socket.  My first error was that I was unable to log in using localhost.  Then I started messing around with the sockets.  Now I'm at a point where even using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost gives me the following error:

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 50:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Socket operation on non-socket
in Connector.php line 50
at PDO->__construct('mysql:unix_socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock;dbname=databasename', 'root', 'notroot', array('0', '2', '0', false, '0')) in Connector.php line 50
at Connector->createConnection('mysql:unix_socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock;dbname=databasename', array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'unix_socket' => '/var/mysql/mysql.sock', 'database' => 'databasename', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => 'notroot', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql'), array('0', '2', '0', false, '0')) in MySqlConnector.php line 22
```

How is this possible?  If I am connecting without using localhost, how come a socket is involved at all?  I have tried so many things and I think I need to reinstall a bunch of stuff at this point but I don't want to lose my databases.  How do I back up my databases without any tools (Sequel Pro doesn't work anymore)?

Answer (score 0):

OK I was able to do this by reinstalling MAMP Pro.  I actually needed to upgrade anyways to 3.4 and so I did.  When I went to WebStart, I saw that that the socket was at /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock, so I changed my line in both Sequel Pro and my Laravel unix socket property in the database.php and it fixed everything.  Hope this helps someone else.